# How to post form data without root url in this perl library

Tags: perl

Setup:
1. To install, do following:
perl -MCPAN -e shell, then, install HTML::Form::XSS

2. I'm using this library for PERL to audit XSS
   https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Form::XSS
3. Perl File will be in HTML-FORM-XSS as check.pl
4. System File Paths: /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1/HTML/Form/XSS.pm

Result 1: perl check.pl https://google.com

```
[-]         Login Form Details      [-]

GET https://www.google.com/search [f]
  ie=ISO-8859-1                  (hidden readonly)
  hl=en-PK                       (hidden readonly)
  source=hp                      (hidden readonly)
  biw=                           (hidden readonly)
  bih=                           (hidden readonly)
  q=                             (text)
  btnG=Google Search             (submit)
  btnI=I'm Feeling Lucky         (submit)
  gbv=1                          (hidden readonly)

[-]                         [-]


[+] Perform Login Injection (y/n): y
[+] Auto Auditing Form for Login Injection

[+] Injected Return Status:200 OK
[+] URL:https://www.google.com/search"
```

Result 2: perl check.pl https://localhost/service/login.asp

```
[-]         Login Form Details      [-]

POST https://localhost/ea/ds-wac-iis.dll [login]
  ontUser=                       (text)
  ontPassword=                   (password)
  Submit=Login                   (submit)
  Help=Help                      (button)

[-]                         [-]


[+] Perform Login Injection (y/n): y
[+] Login Injection

[+] Injected Return Status:302 Object Moved
[+] URL:https://localhost/ea/ds-wac-iis.dll
[+] Injected Return Status:302 Object Moved
[+] URL:https://localhost/ea/ds-wac-iis.dll"
```

QUESTION:

How do I post request or follow redirect for file extensions, I can't figure out much, what's happening here and how to fix it or how to extract more information regarding error as it works fine in php and root url but not in asp, aspx file extensions, WHY IS THAT.

Comment: Are you asking what `check.pl` is doing, which telling us anything about `check.pl`?

Comment: I don't see what question asked in the title of the post has to do with the body of the post.

Comment: Yes exactly, what check.pl is doing. How check.pl is performing all checks and what it can't take urls that don't start from root url, so more information from you and I can dig more into this myself.

Comment: How should we know? We've never seen your file.

Comment: It's unclear what's you mean by "url that starts from root url".